# MultipartServletWebRequest.getFiles() returns empty map

Tags: java, wicket

In Wicket 1.5 we were processed the uploaded files in this way:

```
public UploadValuePage(PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    Bytes maxSize = Bytes.kilobytes(20000);
    ServletWebRequest swr = (ServletWebRequest) getRequest();
    MultipartServletWebRequest mswr = swr.newMultipartWebRequest(maxSize, "uploadId");
    FileItem item = mswr.getFile("fileInput").get(0);
    // process item
}
```

But after migrating to Wicket 6 **there are no files in the map**. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on the web I found this:
http://wicketinaction.com/2012/11/uploading-files-to-wicket-iresource/

So we need an extra line since **Wicket 6.18.0**:

```
public UploadValuePage(PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    Bytes maxSize = Bytes.kilobytes(20000);
    ServletWebRequest swr = (ServletWebRequest) getRequest();
    MultipartServletWebRequest mswr = swr.newMultipartWebRequest(maxSize, "uploadId");
    mswr.parseFileParts(); // since Wicket 6.18.0
    FileItem item = mswr.getFile("fileInput").get(0);
    // process item
}
```